# Error while performing sign and verify operation to a file in Java

Tags: java, security, spring-security

I am using java to perform sign and verify operation and getting below error

> > java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 155 but was expecting 128

Please find my code below to sign and verify

AddSignature

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class AddSignature {

    //The constructor of Message class builds the list that will be written to the file. The list consists of the message and the signature.
    public AddSignature(String data, String keyFile) throws InvalidKeyException, Exception {
        sign(data, keyFile);
    }

    //The method that signs the data using the private key that is stored in keyFile path
    public void sign(String data, String keyFile) throws InvalidKeyException, Exception{
        Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA"); 
        dsa.initSign(getPrivate(keyFile));
        dsa.update(data.getBytes());
        writeToFile("encrypt//destination//data.txt", data.getBytes());
         byte[] sign = dsa.sign();
        writeToFile("encrypt//destination//signed.txt", sign);
    }

    //Method to retrieve the Private Key from a file
    public PrivateKey getPrivate(String filename) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
    }

    private void writeToFile(String signedFileLocation, byte[] signedData) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File f = new File(signedFileLocation);
        f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(signedFileLocation));
        out.writeObject(signedData);
        out.close();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, IOException, Exception{
        String data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type your message here");
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        new AddSignature(data, "MyKeys/privateKey");
    }}
```

VerifySignature

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

public class VerifySignature {

    private static boolean verifySignature(byte[] data, byte[] signature, String keyFile) throws Exception {
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        sig.initVerify(getPublic(keyFile));
        sig.update(data);
        try {
            return sig.verify(signature);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static byte[] read(String fileName) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            fin = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fin.read(fileContent);
            return fileContent;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            fin.close();
        }
    }

    // Method to retrieve the Public Key from a file
    public static PublicKey getPublic(String filename) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePublic(spec);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] data = read("encrypt//destination//data.txt");
        byte[] signed = read("encrypt//destination//signed.txt");
        verifySignature(data, signed, "MyKeys/publicKey");
    }
}
```

I need to sign a file and persist in one location and need to retrieve same file to verify the signature

Answer (score 0):

sth wrong when you retrieve the Private Key from a file. You can have a try like this:

```
public PrivateKey getPrivate(String filename) throws Exception {
  //byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64Utils.decode(readFile(filename));
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
}
private static String readFile(String filePath) throws Exception {
    File inFile = new File(filePath);
    long fileLen = inFile.length();
    Reader reader = new FileReader(inFile);
    char[] content = new char[(int) fileLen];
    reader.read(content);
    System.out.println("read content：" + new String(content));
    return new String(content);
}
```

Comment: it is not working..if i encode ..i am getting below exception                
 Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format